# Old bread-slicing tool

Tags: baking, bread, equipment

Here is an image of an apparently old (and for me, unknown) bread-slicing device from Richard Bertinet’s book “CRUMB” (2019, ISBN: 9780857835543, pg. 105):

What is this particular tool referred to as?

[image]

Comment: FYI devices like this are commonplace in France.  I believe they are called nothing more than "bread slicers" (ie in French).  (Not that particular model, which appears maybe Scandinavian?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I Googled for "Raadvad" which seemed to be the text embossed on the tool, and found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Un5VsIzWkSA) suggesting this is a 'bread guillotine'. A subsequent search for "Raadvad bread guillotine" suggests either 'bread guillotine' or, simply, '([Danish](https://www.myrecipes.com/extracrispy/danish-bread-slicer)/Scandinavian) bread slicer'.

Comment: Common when I was a child in the 70'ies. It is used for black rye bread which is common in Denmark, and Northern Germany. I have also heard it was used for decapitating chicken in animal research, so the nickname guillotine fits.

Comment: I've always called it 'bread guillotine'...but I thought I was being clever..